# Solvable Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

I've read the following fact:

An arbitrary connected solvable Lie group is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n\times T^m$.

Can anyone give me a reference on it? I'm not very familiar with Lie groups and Lie algebras. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a really good series of books on [Lie groups and Lie algebras by Onishchik and Vinberg](https://books.google.com/books?id=l8nJCNiIQAAC&dq=simply+connected+solvable+lie+group+diffeomorphic+to+R%5En&source=gbs_navlinks_s)  (although very pricey). In their third volume, in second chapter, they have a section on the topology of solvable Lie groups.

Here are two results that should help you see why this is the case:

---

**Theorem 3.1** (*page 50-51*)

*Let $G$ be a connected real Lie group.*

*(i) If there is a connected normal Lie subgroup $G_1$ of $G$ of codimension 1, then there exists a 1-dimensional Lie subgroup $C$ of $G$ such that $C \ltimes G_1,$ the semidirect product of $C$ with $G_1$.*

*(ii) If the Lie group $G$ is solvable, then it has a connected normal Lie subgroup of codimension 1.*

---

And then here is part of the succeeding corollary.

---

**Part of a Corollary** (*page 51*)

*Let $G$ be a connected solvable real Lie group. Then there exists one-parameter subgroups $C_i$ of $G$ for $1 \leq i \leq n = dim\, G$ such that: $G = C_1 \cdot C_2 \cdots C_n$ where each element of $g\in G$ is uniquely represented in the form $g = g_1 \cdot g_2 \cdots g_n$ where each $c_i \in C_i$.*

---

This corollary follows from induction on the dimension of the Lie group. A 1-dimensional Lie group has this form. By way of induction, assume $G$ has dimension $n$, and this result holds for dimension less than $n$. By Theorem 3.1, we know that $G = C \ltimes G_1$ where $C$ is 1-dimensional and $G_1$ has dimension less than $n$. Hence, the corollary.

Now, since each element has a unique representation, we can define an explicit diffeomorphism with each element of $G$ with the product of the 1-parameter subgroups $C_i$ i.e. $G \simeq \prod C_i$. Notice that every 1-parameter subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{T}$ and hence diffeomorphic as well. Hence, the claimed diffeomorphism.

Comment: It helps a lot! Thank you very much! @Thomas